# Ext property grid with assigned values in multiselectable combos

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am trying to assign values to a multiselectable combo box in extjs property grid. When I assign some values to the field, the grid fails to render the field. How to resolve this ? Please find the code below.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
   title: 'Properties Grid',
   width: 400,
   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   source: {
       name: "My Object",
       created: Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),
       timeofday: "12:00 PM",
       available: false,
       version: 0.01,
       description: Ext.encode({
           product: 'Clorox',
           tagline: 'The Shinyest White!'            
       }),
       childAccounts:['john','mike']

   },
   customEditors: {
       timeofday: Ext.create('Ext.form.TimeField', {selectOnFocus: true}),
       description: {
           xtype: 'customeditorfield'  
       },
       childAccounts:Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {store: ['john', 'mike', 'harvey'],multiSelect:true}),
   },
   customRenderers: {
       timeofday: function( v ) {
           return Ext.isDate( v ) ? Ext.Date.format( v, 'g:i A' ) : v;
       }
   },
   propertyNames: {
       name: '(name)',
       created: 'Created Date',
       timeofday: 'Time of Day',
       available: 'Available?',
       version: 'Version',
       description: 'Product Description',
       childAccounts: 'Child Description'
   },
   listeners: {
       beforeedit: function( editor, e, opts ) {
           if( e.record.get( 'name' )=='name' || e.record.get( 'name' )=='version' ) {
               return false;            
           }                
       }            
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, only "editable" values are supported by property grid, and Sencha does not count arrays as editable. You can try to override this if you want. The limitation is introduced in `Ext.grid.property.Store.getReader`, where there is a function `isEditableValue`:

```
isEditableValue: function(val){
    return Ext.isPrimitive(val) || Ext.isDate(val) || val === null;
}
```

If you change this function to allow for arrays, it seems to work, but without warranty. I used the following code for quick test:

```
Ext.define('', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.property.Store', 
    getReader: function() {
        var newReader = !this.reader;
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if(newReader) this.reader.isEditableValue = function(val) {
            return Ext.isPrimitive(val) || Ext.isDate(val) || Ext.isArray(val) || val === null;
        }
        return this.reader;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fpi) (Without warranty, as always)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Your "childAccounts" config is not correct. Try to replace:

```
childAccounts:['john','mike']
```

with:

```
childAccounts: 'john, mike'
```

**Notes:**

Tested with ExtJS 4.2.

Comment: now its able to display the childAccounts record in the grid, but the given values are not selected in the dropdown list of the combo box